# how to hot reload html file in webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-loader

I want to build a CSS exercise book just like JSBin or Codepen with the help of webpack hot load feature. But I don't know how to make html file reload in page when it is modified. is there any loader or solution?

Comment: What are you using for loading your HTML now?

Comment: @Brad just use html-webpack-plugin to generate html index file automatically, so I want to inject html content to it and update synchronously